# How to expire orders using sessions

Tags: php, session, cron

I am trying to work out with PHP session and what I want to do is to expire my orders saved in the database after a 30 minutes of inactivity on the order made without payment been completed.

**My Questions**

1. How do I create session to specifically handle the orders in my
       database?
2. How to destroy session {id} generated specifically for orders when
       30mins of inactivity is due?

Just need ideas on how to complete that.

Comment: 1. Why do you need session for handling databases? 2. you would achieve this using server cron, 3. don't understand what are you asking ? If you are saving your order infos into database then why do you need sessions for managing them???

Comment: you should not use sessions for that.

Comment: can u guide me using the server cron

Comment: I have removed thanks note, unnecessary introduction and fixed capitalization mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

*i want to do is to expire my orders saved in the database after a 30 minutes of inactivity on the order made without payment been completed*-

> Use **cron job** .

if you are using database tables to store order information, it will be easy for you to run a cron job, which will run every minute (or every 30 secs, or every 15 secs etc) and will disable/delete all the orders which are inactive from last 30 minutes.

This way disabling inactive orders will also be automatised as well.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php) link for looking how to create a cron.

No need to use sessions if you have to do the above task only.